# iOS Popover or ActionSheet cause UISegmentedControl buttons to be grayed out

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller, uisegmentedcontrol, uiactionsheet

How to remove/change this default effect of grayed out buttons on UISegementedControl while presenting UIPopoverController or UIAlertController with ActionSheet style in iOS 11 and Swift 4.

[image]

Comment: They are greyed out because they are disabled while the popover/alert is in view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `tintAdjustmentMode` to `.normal` on the control or parent view (as opposed to `.automatic`) to prevent dimming during popover or UIAlert presentations.

See [UIViewTintAdjustmentMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622555-tintadjustmentmode#)

This wont affect the fact that they are disabled during the presentation but if its just the coloring you want then this will work.

Also not dimming is a break of the  > iOS7 HIG.

Comment: Yeah, understand that the dimming is normal and correct behavior, and failing to dim controls (like segmented controls) that are disabled is a violation of Apple's human interface guidelines, will cause user confusion, and could cause Apple to reject your app.

Comment: Yeah I know but customer want such design so If it is possible I will do it, and he decide what is better approach for him

Comment: Can I change colouring of this buttons while in this grayed out mode as the text on dark gray segment is nearly invisible. I have also custom adaptive presentation mode and consider also how to switch this UISegmentedControl in this grayed out mode programmatically.

Comment: Ok I found I think I can manually set this tintAdjustmentMode to .dimmed